# "with" databinding on a multi-dimensional array in Knockout Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I have an array that looks something like the following

```
var initData = [
    new Order({
        orderId: "183175",
        name: "Columbus Africentric",
        production: [{
            pType: "Art Time",
            by: "MJ"
        }, {
            pType: "Front Pocket",
            by: "WB"
        }]
    }),
    new Order({
        orderId: "198675",
        name: "Stanford High",
        production: [{
            pType: "Art Time",
            by: "MJ"
        }, {
            pType: "Full Back",
            by: "WB"
        }]
    })
]
```

I'm trying to do a with binding to show only extra information for on order when the item is clicked on.  So I have a foreach for the orders that shows the orderId and the name in a table, and a button to click that then should show all production items for the chosen order. Something like the following

```
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:orders">
     <tr>
     <td>
       <label class="read" data-bind="text:orderId, visible:true" />
     </td>
     <td>
      <label class="read" data-bind="text:name, visible:!$root.isItemEditing($data)" />
     </td>
     <td>
     <td class="tools">
      <div data-bind="if: production"><button data-bind="click: $root.toggleProductionMode">Production</button>
       </div>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-bind="visible: showProductionOrder, with: production">
      <td colspan="5">
      <h3>Production Summary</h3>
       <table class="ko-grid">
           <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Type</th>
              <th>By</th>
            </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody 
              <tr>
              <td>
               <label class="read" data-bind="text:pType, visible:!$root.isItemEditing($data)" />
               </td>                     
                <td>
                 <label class="read" data-bind="text:by, visible:!$root.isItemEditing($data)" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody> 
     </table>
  </tr>
```

I think I need to use a foreach to get to the production information. Can a foreach binding be used inside a with binding? Or do I even need one? If I have it bound using the "with" binding, is there a certain way to get to the multiple production items? I know this is super easy and it's probably staring me right in the face.

also, when creating the Item Model I'm doing the following, which I think might be incorrect.

```
function Order(data) {
    self.orderId = ko.observable();
    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.production = ko.observableArray([
        [   
            self.pType = ko.observable(),
            self.by = ko.observable()
        ]
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a new table inside the main table. For a child collection you have to use "ko foreach: production" as a html comment and then add your tr tags afterwards to display the production items. Have a look into this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkhokhar/Z7CJA/7/) example.

```
// HTML
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Student ID</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Students">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: StudentID"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: StudentName"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: Courses -->
            <tr>
                <td style='padding-left:20px;' data-bind="text: CourseID"></td>
                <td  style='padding-left:20px;' data-bind="text: CourseName"></td>
            </tr>
         <!-- /ko -->
    </tbody>
</table>

// KNOCKOUT CODE

function StudentViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Students = [
        { StudentID: "1", StudentName: "Ali", 
           Courses: [ { CourseID: "100", CourseName: "Math" }, { CourseID: "102", CourseName: "Physics" } ] 
        },
        { StudentID: "2", StudentName: "Isa" ,
         Courses: [ { CourseID: "103", CourseName: "Chemistry" }, { CourseID: "104", CourseName: "Social Studies"   } ] },
        { StudentID: "3", StudentName: "Zoya" ,
        Courses: [ { CourseID: "100", CourseName: "Math" }, { CourseID: "106", CourseName: "Stats" } ] },
    ];
}

ko.applyBindings(new StudentViewModel());
```

Comment: I'm still having issues with initializing the variables. I come up with javascript error "unable to parse bindings, pType is not defined" I know it has to be the way I am initializing the object. can you take a look here -> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjiles/pCUe6/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there anything specific that needs to be done while pushing new objects into array?

Comment: You have to make the Student array as observable. See here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkhokhar/Z7CJA/11/)